# Thread-based early exit code no longer works

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exit

I've been using the following script to end my loop based programs early and it has worked well until just recently. I haven't changed anything and there are no errors to troubleshoot but it doesn't do what it should. Thanks in advance for any assist.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'fileutils'
Thread.new do
  while line = STDIN.gets
    break if line.chomp == 'x'
  end
  # do something here usually a puts or writing files
  #end
  exit
end

BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'
BASE_DIR = '/some.php?'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(BASE_URL))
last_pg = page.xpath('//*[@id="wgo_stats"]/div/p[1]/a').map {|lastpg| lastpg['href'].split('?')[-1].split('-')[0].to_i}.first

puts "Current Index: #{last_pg}"

for pg_number in 1..last_pg do
  puts "Getting #{pg_number}"
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{BASE_URL}#{BASE_DIR}#{pg_number}"))
  @results << page.xpath('//*[@id="breadcrumb"]/ul/li[2]/span').text.delete(' ') + ':' + page.xpath('//*[@id="breadcrumb"]/ul/li[2]/span').text.delete(' ')
end
```

Comment: What is your thread supposed to do?

Comment: Exit the loop and end the program early after I input 'x' and enter.

Comment: And now it doesn't exit?

Comment: Correct, it did before my most recent updated to that particular script (where i didn't change anything about the thread) and it works just fine in other scripts I've written. I'm going to try rebooting my dev environment.

Comment: Yes but I want the program to do something during the exit; I've commented out the particulars but In this case it should be writing a file with the captured data up until that point.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. In these cases I try commenting out code until it works that way i can pin point what line is causing the problem and then I can debug that or ask a more specific question.